# Using Google Analytics to build user data in website

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I have recently setup some good detailed reporting in Google Analytics on an eCommerce website, and am using the eCommerce addition to Google Analytics.

I am trying to work out how I could get this data to know the following about each user:

- unique identifier
- order history
- add to basket history

I have all the order and basket history in Analytics, but some how I need to build some kind of database with this data in against each user so I can personalise my website for each user.

Could anyone point me in a right direction to start this process please.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you would like to pull out data from Google Analytics to your application and then show content accordingly? To my knowledge it is not possible to retrieve data from analytics about specific users in this way.

To show content/promotions based on previous purchases you will need to take this data directly from your application, since the user data is already in the database. You will probably need a 3rd party plugin, depending on which application you use.

I hope this answers your question. If you can give more info about your platform and kind of products I'll might be able to come with more solutions.

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to reply. You have understood me correctly here. Much like Amazon I am trying to work out the most efficient and accurate way to show the users recently viewed history (that has not been purchased) email a logged in user the contents of their shopping basket if it has not been purchased, and really start profiling each individual user even if they are not logged in. The site I am working on is a custom .net platform.